# How can I prevent fixed width elements from being pushed around?

Tags: css, html

I currently have a footer that uses a 3 column layout with a fixed center and fluid sides in order to get a nice box shadow effect. When the window is too small however, it pushes the footer to the left, and messes everything up.

**I can't seem to figure out how to make sure the footer divs do not get pushed around. I keep running into this problem with my layouts.**

The [layout I am working on is here](http://kin.remuria.net/layouttest.html), and [a screencast showing the problem is here](http://screencast.com/t/sATFawFPL0).

Comment: Please take a look at my revised solution, and my alternative solution. See if either solves your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is simply to add `min-width:980px` to `#container`.

```
#container {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #A8D9A7;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
    min-width: 980px; /* add this */
}
```

The `980px` figure comes from the `width:960px` + `padding-left:10px` + `padding-right:10px` of the `#content-container`.

Answer (score 1):

The container element for your main page body (`<div id="body">`) has computed `padding-left` of `10px`, and the second container element, (`<div id="content-container">`) adds another `padding-left` of `10px`, meaning your main body is padded from the left by `20px`.

Whereas the container for your footer (`<div id="footer-container">`) has computed `padding-left` of `0`.

<strike>If you add this, it will fix your problem. `#footer-container {padding: 0 20px;}`</strike>
Revised as the above solution messed up bottom `box-shadow`.

In the `#footer-left-outer {` rule change:

```
margin-right:470px;
```

to:

```
margin-right:-490px;
```

In the `#footer-right-outer {` rule change:

```
margin-left:-470px;
```

to:

```
margin-left:-490px;
```

In the `#footer {` rule change:

```
padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
width: 940px;
```

to:

```
padding: 10px 30px;
width: 980px;
```

I now understand why you were using the `outer-right` and `outer-left`.

---

I found a different solution that includes the partial `box-shadow` effect:
http://jsfiddle.net/nottrobin/Cr4NF/10/

It avoids the need for `footer-left-outer` and `footer-right-outer` but I'll leave it up to you to decide if it's neater.

It makes use of `:before` which only works in IE8 onwards:
http://caniuse.com/#search=:before
But then `box-shadow` doesn't work in IEs < 9 anyway:
http://caniuse.com/#search=box-shadow

Comment: That works, but it causes the box-shadow to cut off unfortunately.

Comment: I updated my solution to one that doesn't mess up your `box-shadow`

Comment: Right. Revised again. I believe this should now be your solution.